# WPF MVVM app: GC releases memory after 10 minutes (not a memory leak!)

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, .net-7.0

An MVVM WPF app in C# (.NET 7.0), best practices, clean code.

#### Observation

Initially, the application needs **200 MB** or RAM. After populating lists with a lot of data, about **1500 MB** of memory is used, because it's a lot of data.

When clearing the lists, it takes about 10 minutes - after that, memory use is back to **200 MB** again.

#### The issue

So, the memory is, indeeed, not leaked, but reclaimed by the GC. There is **no memory leak** to be analyzed. But why does it take 10 minutes?

`GC.Collect` or even `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true)` seem to have no effect, or only about 10 MB. Despite the fact that this method should not be called for no good reason, it doesn't have any effect either.

#### My question:

**What can I do to have unused and unreferenced memory reclaimed faster?** Because memory use above 1 GB for extended periods of time raises questions to the end user - and the developer is left unaware whether this is a memory leak or not, unless the developer decides to wait 10 minutes to find out.

#### Edit: Attempt to manually do a full GC

As by the suggestions from @Npras, I am using following code to try and force a complete GC:

```
GC.AddMemoryPressure(nint.MaxValue);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Aggressive, true, true);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced, false);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(nint.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Are you using any native memory that is released in a finalizer? Is this in a UI program? I have seen windows accessibility holding on to references longer than it should in WPF programs. In either case, you should use a memory profiler to find out if there is any references to the memory.

Comment: the memory allocation and deallocation is a price operation. That is why memory that has been released by the app is not released immediately by the .NET for the process. The memory is supposed to be used by the process again. `because it's a lot of data` probably the app is displaying a lot of data and need a lot of controls to display that data. You may want to consider some filtering before data is shown (and populated by the app. Like showing the latest 200 records when app is started.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your items are being held in the [Large Object Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) (LOH). The GC usually just does a 'sweep' to mark unused regions of the LOH, but does not perform any compaction. Defragmenting large objects is *expensive*.

You could try specifying [CompactOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode) before your blocking `GC.Collect` to force LOH compaction, and see if it helps.

```
using System.Runtime; 
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
```

Comment: `CompactOnce` alone didn't seem to have effect, but an additional `GC.AddMemoryPressure` did. However, doing this several times was required to release memory. Looks like unmanaged resources, possibly by WPF (?)...

Comment: I've come across several workarounds on what `GC` methods to call in what order to achieve complete garbage collection. However none of them really do a complete collection reliably. Did you find out more? (+1)

Comment: @bytecode77, speaking of WPF, have you tried testing on a Release build, without a debugger connected? WPF debugging interfaces tend to cling on to things.  Also, have you tried the other comment about memory profiling? The Visual Studio memory snapshots can show you what memory is still uncollected and the references holding on to them (under *Paths to Root*).

Comment: Yes, Release mode. Something else is clinging, as even a forced GC (see my edited question) does not immediately clear memory. Another interesting observation is that memory drops to **80 MB** after half an hour.